# How to suppress R.Net console output?

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I have the following code that uses R.Net on Windows:

```
engine = REngine.GetInstance();
engine.Initialize();
engine.Evaluate("library(tseries)");
```

Unfortunately it outputs some messages to the console which I want to suppress.

I tried using the `NullCharacterDevice` in `Initialize` and the `invisible` R function but unfortunately they did not suppress the output of the evaluate call.

```
engine = REngine.GetInstance();
engine.Initialize(null, new NullCharacterDevice());
engine.Evaluate("invisible(library(tseries))");
```

How can I suppress all console output of R.Net?

Comment: `engine.Evaluate("suppressWarnings(library(tseries, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = TRUE))")` you could also wrap it arround `suppressMessages` function if there are messages that you dont want

Comment: Change the `warn.conflicts = FALSE`